# Scale with variable resolution

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scale

I'm working on a paint application using Python's `tkinter` package.

I am making a Scale widget to handle zooming. I want the user to be able to zoom `0.5x, 1x, 2x, and 4x`. The problem is, the resolutions are changing.

> From 0.5 to 1 the resolution is 0.5.
>
> From 1 to 2 the resolution is 1.
>
> From 2 to 4 the resolution is 2.

Is it possible to declare a Scale widget with varying resolutions?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745011/tkinter-slider-scale-with-discrete-steps/25745136#25745136

Comment: *"I'm working on a paint application using Python's tkinter package"* - that might be your first mistake, I'm not sure Tkinter is the best tool for that job.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah it definitely isnt but Im just doing it for fun