# How can I make a Tkinter slider that scales logarithmically?

Tags: python, tkinter

On the slider, the values will vary from 0.05 to 100 (1 as the center) and as the user changes slider's position, it will update the output logarithmically as shown in the image:

[image]

How can I modify the intervals (labels under the slider) and the output in such a way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use tkinter slider \`Scale\` widget with discrete steps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745011/how-to-use-tkinter-slider-scale-widget-with-discrete-steps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can math it by setting a `command` for your `Scale` widget::

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="1.00")
label.pack()
scale = tk.Scale(root, from_=-20, to=20, tickinterval=0.1, orient="horizontal", showvalue=0)
scale.config(command=lambda e: label.config(text=f"{10**(scale.get()/10):.2f}"))
scale.pack()

root.mainloop()
```